# Which verb do you use when a gun fired?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I need a verb that describes a sound of a single shot from a long-barrel 17-19 century gun or a rifle.

I did some research and I found that:

***Rumble*** is used with big guns, cannons.

***Rattle*** is about continous fire, like machine gun or many rifles.

***Thunder*** seems to be about big guns again.

Can I still use one of these verbs or is there a better option?

*The gun rumbled, and he flew backwards into the ditch.*

Comment: 'Crack' is quite common with small-arms (pistol, revolver, rifle, etc.). There is not just one word.

Comment: As a historical reenactor, I can tell you that a pre-20th century firearm made a noticeably different sound from a modern one, but it certainly wasn't a rumble. One _noun_ for the sound of a shot is _report_.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you're concerned with [onomatopoeia (ονοματοποιία)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia), "the process of creating a word that phonetically imitates, resembles, or suggests the sound that it describes."

Aristophanes used it in ancient Greece for [the croak of frogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frogs): Brekekekèx-koàx-koáx (Βρεκεκεκὲξ κοὰξ κοάξ), mentioned by Major General Srtanley in Gilbert and Sullivan in *The Pirates of Penzance*: "I know the croaking chorus from The Frogs of Aristophanes".

The website [Onomatopoeia Dictionary](http://www.writtensound.com/index.php?term=weapon) has a considerable list of weapon sounds, but if you don't find *exactly* the right orthography, consider creating your own [neologism](https://owlcation.com/humanities/The-Creation-of-New-Words)... but let your instructor know your intention to expand on onomatopoeia. He or she will get a bang from your efforts!